# Hauptmoduls for modular curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, modular-forms

If I have a modular curve, how does one in general find a Hauptmodul for this curve?

Comment: In general one does not, since (here I assume we are talking about congruence subgroups of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$) there are only finitely many modular curves of genus zero.  This finite list is known and Hauptmoduls have been written down, probably more than a century ago in most cases.  Would you be satisfied by references to the literature, or is there more to your question than that?

Comment: Yes I would definitely be satisfied by references. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As Pete mentions in the comments, computing Hauptmoduls for genus zero modular curves has a long history (results go back to work by Klein and Gierster published in 1879). Since those early works, there have been many papers on Hauptmodules. For a nice discussion about Hauptmodules (including references to the aforementioned papers of Klein and Gierster) see
*[On Rationally Parametrized Modular Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611041)* by Robert Maier, which includes a table of Hauptmoduls for $X_0(N)$ on page 11. Though one can construct Hauptmoduls for $X_0(N)$ using eta-functions, this does not work in general. In general one can instead use Siegel functions (or the closely related Klein forms) (see especially [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03988) by Sutherland and Zywina which explains a general procedure for constructing Hauptmoduls from Siegel functions starting on page 11). (One can also construct Hauptmodules from ["generalized eta-functions"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869304001395), which are essentially Siegel functions.)